# Using @font-face for woff2 file not downloading in chrome and IE browser

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, google-chrome, woff2

I am using NodeJS with AngularJS in my application running on the Ubuntu 12.04 operating system.In my css file I am using the @font-face where I used the .woff2 font file extension.When I run the application on the browser , I am getting 404 for the all the .woff2 files in my chrome and also in IE.Can anyone help me resolve this issue. The font files are placed correctly in the given path.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'PT Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('PT Sans'), local('PTSans-Regular'), url(../font/PT_Sans_Regular.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that path to font file is correct? IE does not support woff2 font format

Comment: yes the path I am using for font file was correct.I can able to get the ttf files from same path.